How to catch error in XMLHttpRequest call with caller function
I am building a feature in ReactJS that allows a user to upload files to a photos app.  My backend validates the files to ensure they are of a supported type, and not some random type like .txt or .bat or some other non-image file type.  If the user attempts to upload an unsupported type, the server responds with an HTTP 415 error "Unsupported Media Type."  I'm able to access this status code in the function that sent this request, shown below:
export function sendCSRFRequest(formData, targetURL) {  
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // check for HTTP response status
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                console.log("Upload successful!");
            } else if (request.status === 415) {
                throw new Error("Can't upload that!");
            }
        }
    };

    request.open('POST', targetURL);
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    request.send(formData);
};

This code successfully identifies the 415 error and throws the error to the console with text, "Can't upload that!"  But what I want to do is hand this error back to the calling function so I can do some conditional rendering and show the user an alert that tells them what went wrong directly in the UI.  Here is the calling function:
async function handleUpload(e, files, setFiles, setUploadFailed) {
    e.preventDefault() // do not redirect page
    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach(file => {formData.append('file', file)});
    try {
        sendCSRFRequest(formData, 'api/upload/'); // Function shown above
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Found an error!");
        console.error(e);
        setUploadFailed(true); // Triggers an alert in the UI
    }
    
    await setFiles([]); // If upload is successful, clear out state "files"
};

This second function doesn't seem to be catching the error I am throwing in the first function, and I can't understand why.  I've tried setting up my try/catch block in various ways, adding and removing "await" on various lines, changing to sendCSRFRequest().catch(e => /* do something */), nothing I try seems to work.  Does the error thrown in the sendCSRFRequest function not bubble all the way back up to the calling function for some reason?  Do I need to do something different when throwing the error so that it will bubble back up to the caller?  Am I not properly catching the error as it bubbles back up?

note: if you MUST use XMLHttpRequest, try using load, loadend, error events instead of readystatechange ... personally, I'd use fetch API instead, since it already uses Promise, therefore no fuxing with new Promise required

This is what I ended up doing, I switched to the fetch API, it worked better with what I needed to do.  I may answer this post later with the solution I used for anyone with the same question.  Thank you for the suggestion!

See readystatechange event
onreadystatechange event is not synchronous.
It won't wait the response of sendCSRFRequest and continue executing.
You can try to use Promisified method.
export function sendCSRFRequest(formData, targetURL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // check for HTTP response status
        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Upload successful!");
                    resolve();
                    return;
                } else if (request.status === 415) {
                    reject("Can't upload that!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            reject("Somthing went wrong!");
        };

        request.open('POST', targetURL);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        request.send(formData);
    });
}

And call it with await.
async function handleUpload(e, files, setFiles, setUploadFailed) {
    e.preventDefault() // do not redirect page
    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach(file => {formData.append('file', file)});
    try {
        await sendCSRFRequest(formData, 'api/upload/'); // Function shown above
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Found an error!");
        console.error(e);
        setUploadFailed(true); // Triggers an alert in the UI
    }
    
    await setFiles([]); // If upload is successful, clear out state "files"
};

